# Separable Function: Alternative Representation

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, complex-numbers

How does one get the following function

$$
f(u) = f(x+iy) = \frac{u^{z-1}}{e^{-u}-1},
$$

where $z$ is a constant complex number and u is a complex variable, into the form:

$$
f(x+iy) = v(x,y) + iw(x,y)
$$

?

Best Regards,

J.B

Comment: This looks suspiciously like the analytic continuation of the riemann zeta function

Comment: It is! :) @TylerHG

Comment: Do you see a method that would apply to reduce it into this form? @TylerHG

Comment: @TylerHG,can you find a solution using the method mentioned by the user below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few basic exercises to get you started.

1. Write $(\alpha+i\beta)\cdot(\gamma+i\delta)$ in the form $\square+i\square$.
2. Write $(\alpha+i\beta)/(\gamma+i\delta)$ in the form $\square+i\square$.
3. Write $e^{\alpha+i\beta}$ in the form $\square+i\square$.
4. Write $\alpha+i\beta$ as $\square e^{i\square}$ (polar form).
5. Write $\log(re^{i\theta})$ as $\square+i\square$.

Once you can do all of these, you can solve your problem. (Since $u^{z-1}=e^{(\log u)(z-1)}$.)

Comment: How would you write $e^{\alpha+i\beta}$ in the form of $\square+i\square$ when the variables can vary?Thank You!@blue

Comment: @DifferentialEquations Can you write $e^{i\beta}$ in that form, first?

Comment: It would be $\ cos(\beta)+isin(\beta)$ , right? @blue

Comment: Yep. So can you write $e^{\alpha+i\beta}$ as $\square+i\square$?

Comment: However, how can you treat -u as a angle? @blue

Comment: $u^{z-1}=e^{(\log u)(z-1)}$. Figure out how to proceed from there using the exercises I gave you. First, write $u$ in polar, then find $\log u$'s real and imaginary parts, then expand the product $(\log u)(z-1)$, then exponentiate using the rule you have for that.

Comment: How would you express $\ e^{\alpha+i\beta}$ as a complex number?@blue

Comment: Hint: $e^{\alpha+i\beta}=e^\alpha e^{i\beta}$.

Comment: So it would be $\ e^{\alpha}cos(\beta)+ie^{\alpha}sin(\beta)$@blue?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Lastly $\square e^{i\square}=(√(\alpha^{2}+\beta^{2}))e^{itan^{-1}(\frac {\beta}{\alpha})}$?@blue

Comment: You mean $\alpha+i\beta=\sqrt{\alpha^2+\beta^2}e^{i\theta}$. What's $\theta$ in terms of $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

Comment: Yes sorry,is it =$(√(\alpha^{2}+\beta^{2}))e^{i(tan)^{-1}(\frac {\beta}{\alpha})}$?@blue

Comment: Yes. More standard to write `\sqrt{\alpha^2+\beta^2}`, not `(\sqrt(\alpha^2+\beta^2))`.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Is $\ ln(re^{i\theta})=ln(r)+i\theta$ ?@blue

Comment: Yes, assuming $\theta$ is in the appropriate range.

Comment: Dear @blue, I followed your steps and formulated the following result: $\frac{((\sqrt{x^2+y^2})^{z-1}\cos(\tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x})z-\tan^{-1}(\frac {y}{x})))((e^{-x}\cos(y)-1)-(e^{-x}\sin(y)) ((\sqrt{x^2+y^2})^{z-1}\sin(\tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x})z-\tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x}))))}{((e^{-x}\cos(y)-1)^{2} + (e^{-x}\sin(y))^{2})}+\frac{i((e^{-x}\sin(y)) ((\sqrt{x^2+y^2})^{z-1}\cos(\tan^{-1}(\frac {y}{x})z-\tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x})))+((\sqrt{x^2+y^2})^{z-1}\sin(\tan^{-1}(\frac {y}{x})z-\tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x})))(e^{-x}\cos(y)-1))}{((e^{-x}\cos(y)-1)^2+(e^{-x}\sin(y))^2)}$. How do I verify that this is correct?

Comment: Sorry, there is an error in the code.Is there an alternative way I can send it to you?@blue

Comment: @DifferentialEquations Click the "answer your own question" button below. You're not going to actually answer your own question. Instead, slowly build the equation and use the automatic preview to tell where you're messing up. Also see the many latex guides around the web, and also here on meta.math.stackexchange. Or write it, scan it, upload it, link it.

Comment: By the way, I have no interest in actually computing the real and imaginary parts of this expression as a function of the real and imaginary parts of $u$ and $z$. It is unenlightening, and will surely be of no help in understanding the Riemann zeta function. Indeed, it could only distract from that goal. Besides, if you were not already knowledgeable about how to do basic arithmetic with complex numbers, then you probably need to first learn more basic complex analysis before trying your hand at this level of stuff.

Comment: Dear @blue, I identified the problem; here it is: $\frac {(((√{x^{2}+y^{2}})^{z-1}cos(tan^{-1}(\frac {y}{x})z-tan^{-1}(\frac {y}{x})))((e^{-x}cos(y)-1)-(e^{-x}sin(y))((√{x^{2}+y^{2}})^{z-1}sin(tan^{-1}(\frac {y}{x})z-tan^{-1}(\frac {y}{x}))))} {((e^{-x}cos(y)-1)^{2}+(e^{-x}sin(y))^{2})}$ $+i\frac {(((e^{-x}sin(y))((√{x^{2}+y^{2}})^{z-1}cos(tan^{-1}(\frac {y}{x})z-tan^{-1}(\frac {y}{x})))+((√{x^{2}+y^{2}})^{z-1}sin(tan^{-1}(\frac {y}{x})z-tan^{-1}(\frac {y}{x})))(e^{-x}cos(y)-1)))}{((e^{-x}cos(y)-1)^{2}+(e^{-x}sin(y))^{2})}$

Comment: Actually, the first expression I sent to you was correct.@blue